# Query construction for date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've the following initial data:
[image]

what I want to come with is:

[image]

Here is the logic: for each 'Rest' value of a particular 'accNumber', I want to put into 'date_in' minimum date of that particular 'Rest' value, and for 'date_fin' I want to put 'date'-1 value of next coming 'date' of 'Rest' attribute of the same 'accNumber'. I shouldn't select rows with 0 'Rest' value. One more problem is for the last 'Rest' value of particular accNumber, there is no upcoming date with same 'accNumber', so we should simply take last value of date as date_fin (you can observe this on tables provided. Here is pleminary work I've done, but it doesn't work as I want:

```
SELECT a.accNumber, a.Rest, MIN(a.Date), MIN(b.Date)
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b ON a.accNumber=b.accNumber 
WHERE a.Date<b.Date 
AND a.Rest<>0 
AND a.accNumber=b.accNumber
GROUP BY a.accNumber, a.Rest
ORDER BY a.accNumber
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Er, you say you don't want to select the `Rest = 0` rows, but it appears your result rows include the data from them (the 'date - 1').  Which is correct?  Note that, due to the way variable-precision types work ([especially timestamps in SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), you'd be better off storing/using the exclusive upper bound for the dates.

Comment: It takes only date values from them and does not include 0 rest values at all

Answer (score 0):

Ok Now that I understood your problem I made a little example that should work, the editor didn't let me format the code sorry

```
select 
    accNumber,rest, min(Date) date_in, Max(Date) date_fin, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY accNumber ORDER BY MIN(date)) AS Row
INTO #tmp
from table1
GRoup By accNumber,rest
order by accNumber,date_in
select a.accNumber,a.rest, a.date_in, ISNULL(DATEADD(dd,-1,b.date_in),a.date_fin)date_fin
from #tmp a
LEFT JOIN #tmp b ON a.accNumber=b.accNumber and a.Row = b.Row - 1 
where a.rest != 0
order by a.accNumber,a.date_in
drop table #tmp
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not something that I want, date_fin isn't just max date, it is minimum date -1 of upcoming rest value

Comment: Oh sorry I misundestood the question! Are you using a stored procedure?

Comment: I don't know exactly what does that mean, but most probably I don't use it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem you want the start date & end date to be grouped by accnumber & rest where rest <> 0

```
   SELECT A.ACCNUMBER, A.REST, MIN(DATE) AS 'DATE_IN',(SELECT 
    MAX(B.DATE) FROM TABLE1 B 
    WHERE 
    A.DATE<B.DATE AND
    A.REST <> 0 AND
    A.ACCNUMBER = B.ACCNUMBER) AS 'DATE_FIN'
    FROM TABLE1 A
    GROUP BY ACCNUMBER, REST
    ORDER BY ACCNUMBER
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I want. I want DATE_FIN to be date of upcoming 'date' - 1 of the different 'Rest' value